# Retrieve data from the new Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the new Firebase at firebase.google.com for my website.
My database structure: 
root 
___ [auto-generated ID] 
 
______ key1 : value 
______ key2 : value 

I followed the method in their document to get value of key1 as below:

```
database.ref('root/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var obj = snapshot.val();
    alert(obj[0].key1);
});
```

But I always get the error says that obj[0] is undefined and I can't read its properties. What did I do wrong and how to properly retrieve data from firebase? 
Note: I'm using Angularjs for my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! `alert(obj[0].key1);` gives you the error!

instead, try using the below code:

```
database.ref('root/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var obj = snapshot.val();
    obj.forEach(function(data){
        alert(data.key());
    }
});
```

Also the usage of `/root` is not advised. Instead, use the url of the data.

The normal format of this url is: `<uniqueAppName>.firebaseio.com`

```
var url = "dazzling-inferno-2613.firebaseio.com";
database.ref(url).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    //concepts
});
```